# Increase in memory usage with every LSTM test run

Tags: memory, lstm

I run an LSTM in a test mode. Every time an LSTM is called and makes an output, the internal memory usage increases (output is a single float or just a few floats, so that shouldn't be the issue) until my memory is all used and the program gets terminated due to the lack of memory. Is it a right observation and LSTM behavior, and if so what could be done about it?

Answer (score 0):

The increase in memory usage was caused by the Autograd engine. Turning it off with
`with torch.no_grad_()` solves the memory issue.